# Accessing the Custom View in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am trying to create a icon and a short description below it. I have created a customised View class with a ImageView and a TextView and i integrated it with my xml file, now the imageView and the default text appears in the screen,i don't know how to change the text content of the textview or the source of the imageview.

MyView.java

```
package sda.jk;

public class MyView extends LinearLayout{

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        LayoutInflater li=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v= li.inflate(R.layout.myview, this);
    }

}
```

myview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        />
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="my view"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/sda.jk"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<sda.jk.MyView
        android:id="@+id/myView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


    </sda.jk.MyView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step-1** First assign id to image view and text view in myview. xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/myImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/myText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="my view"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Step-2**
initialize your own view in oncreate method using

```
MyView mv = (MyView)findViewById(R.id.myView1);
```

**step-3**
initilize image view and text view using findViewById method of your own view

```
TextView textView = (TextView) mv.findViewById(R.id.myText);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) mv.findViewById(R.id.myImage);
```

**step-4**
set text to text view using setText method

```
textView.setText("Sunil Kumar Sahoo");
```

set background image to image view using

```
imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

Your oncreate method will be like the following (from step-2 to step-4)

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);
        MyView mv = (MyView)findViewById(R.id.myView1);
        TextView textView = (TextView) mv.findViewById(R.id.myText);
        textView.setText("Sunil Kumar Sahoo");
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) mv.findViewById(R.id.myImage);
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You write a function in sda.jk.MyView for setting text. For changing text, just call the function with a string parameter

```
 Class MyView extends LinearLayout
 {
     //...

     public void setUserText(String str)
     {
          textview.setText(str);
     }

     //...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a useful feature in TextView called compund drawables, which allows you to incorporate a drawable to be drawn above, below, left or right of your text.
use  it like so:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt"
    android:text="my compound drawable textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/xxxxx" />
```

you can use drawableBottom, drawableLeft etc.. as well.
this way you don't need to implement your own class.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom attributes by writing a custom attr.xml and loading the attributes in your custom view's constructor. For a full example check this page 
http://javawiki.sowas.com/doku.php?id=android:custom-view-attributes

Answer (score 0):

For accessing individual elements from a View hierarchy, use the `findViewById` method. Refer to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById%28int%29

You would have to provide identifiers to your view elements in your XML thus:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="my view" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and refer them from your custom view class thus:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imgView);
TextView textView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtView);
```

Typically, you would like to keep the views as instance variables (members) so that you can change them from other methods.